# How add animation for SwipeToDismiss (nhaarman | ListViewAnimations)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I use lib [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) by nhaarman.

Сreated ListView and enableSwipeToDismiss:

```
listView = new MainCurrencyListView(getContext());


adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), items);

SimpleSwipeUndoAdapter simpleSwipeUndoAdapter = new SimpleSwipeUndoAdapter(adapter, getContext(), new SwipeOnDismissCallback(adapter));
AlphaInAnimationAdapter animAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(simpleSwipeUndoAdapter);
animAdapter.setAbsListView(listView);
assert animAdapter.getViewAnimator() != null;
animAdapter.getViewAnimator().setInitialDelayMillis(INITIAL_DELAY_MILLIS);
listView.setAdapter(animAdapter);

//DragAndDrop
listView.enableDragAndDrop();
listView.setOnItemMovedListener(new ListItemMovedListener(adapter));
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListItemLongClickListener(listView));

/* Enable swipe to dismiss */
listView.enableSimpleSwipeUndo();
```

This list with drag and drop, and removing elements from the cancellation.

I would like to make a list with drag and drop and easy removal without canceling.

The application example, there is called '*Swipe-To-Dismiss*', but in the code '*example*' on github I did not see this implementation.

Please help, how it can be implemented?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution found and we can not say that it is intuitive:

```
/* Enable swipe to dismiss */
//listView.enableSimpleSwipeUndo();
listView.enableSwipeToDismiss(new SwipeOnDismissCallback(adapter));
```

That is, you need to create first **SimpleSwipeUndoAdapter**. (That was the animation after the removal of the item)

And then instead of **enableSimpleSwipeUndo();** do **enableSwipeToDismiss(new SwipeOnDismissCallback(adapter));**

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it like in [this](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) article. You don't need any special libraries. I'm sure it is good article because I did it few days ago using this tutorial.

Comment: Big thx for answer and link! I will definitely look. But I would like to understand and deal with the question that I asked :)